# Syntax error in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code. When I run it, i get the following error:

```
File "app.py", line 16
    @app.route('/')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I remove these lines

```
try:
    tree = ET.parse('export.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
```

I do not have the error anymore. I don't understand what is the problem and how can I fix it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

file = open("/home/ubuntu/flaskapp/export.xml", 'w')
file.write(r.text)
file.close()

try:
    tree = ET.parse('export.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I'd say you need to catch the exception in a full try/except block

Comment: a `try` must have an `except` or a `finally` even if they do nothing...

Comment: This fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added except for try, code works now.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

file = open("/home/ubuntu/flaskapp/export.xml", 'w')
file.write(r.text)
file.close()

try:
    tree = ET.parse('export.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

except Exception :
    print "The database is stopped!\n"

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```